# Using the subprocess module to open more than one application

Tags: python

Can I run more than one application, like a word processor, from `subprocess`?

```
import subprocess

self.commandLinkButton_2.clicked.connect(self.pycharm)

self.commandLinkButton_6.clicked.connect(self.terminal)

def pycharm(self):
    subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/pycharm'])

def terminal(self):
    subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/terminal'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to use `subprocess.Popen` instead, and turn off `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` by setting them to `None`. Try these:

```
def pycharm(self):
    subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/pycharm'], stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None)

def terminal(self):
    subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/terminal'], stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None)
```